# convert several png to one pdf

Tags: pdf, convert, png

I have 280 pgn files that I want to merge and convert into one pdf.

PNG files names are in the sequence p000.png, p001.png etc and total space is about 30mb.

I did:

```
convert p00*.png to myfile.pdf
```

and it worked fine. Luckly enough in the right order.

But when I do:

```
conver p*.png to myfile.pdf
```

It consumes all my 4Gb of memory and half my swap. Then it crashes with the error

```
convert: memory allocation failed `myfile.pdf' @ error/pdf.c/WritePDFImage/1595.
```

Any idea of how to make a workaround to this problem?

I think that a good enough solution would be to use `convert` one file at a time to pdf, with the same name. Then use `pdfunite` or `pdftk` to merge them. But I don't know how to use `convert`  in this way.

Comment: You could just use `pdflatex` to place all the pngs on one pdf. More infos are on [TeX.SX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Imagemagick seems to be very violent with memory usage. A suggestion is to use -limit to limit the memory size convert will use, it should use a disk cache for anything else it needs. Read an explanation here:

http://www.imagemagick.org/pipermail/magick-users/2002-March/001285.html

And here's how to use the -limit option : http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#limit

If not, you can do it like you describe, converting each image individually and then merging them with some other tool. Something like

```
for name in p*.png; do convert $name `basename $name .png`.pdf; done
```

should do it.

Basically it iterates over all the png files, runs convert on them, the only magic is the `basename $name .png` part, which will be replaced by the filename minus the .png part, so that when attaching .pdf extension to it, the filename makes sense.

Try it for yourself so you get a feel of what basename does:

```
basename something.png .png
echo `basename something.png .png`.pdf
```

Comment: I had to play around with the limit option and it finally worked with "-limit memory 128MiB -limit map 256MiB". Also "basename" was a cool thing to learn. Thanks